# Visual Studio 2012 C# Manually adding information to the database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, migration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using OrdersApp.Models;

namespace OrdersApp.DAL
{
    public class OrderInitializer : System.Data.Entity. DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OrderContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(OrderContext context)
        {
            var orders = new List<Order>
            {
            new Order { OrderId = 1, OrderNumber = 0001, OrderDate = "03/09/2015", OrderTotal = 120, OrderShippingAmount = 12, OrderStatus = "Not Shipped", CustomerEmail = "lostaunaum@gmail.com", CustomerName = "Marco Andre Lostaunau", CustomerAddress1 = "803 Jessie St.", CustomerAddress2 = "", CustomerState = "TX", CustomerZip = 78704, CustomerCity = "Austin", CustomerCountry = "United States"},

            new Order { OrderId = 2, OrderNumber = 0002, OrderDate = "03/09/2015", OrderTotal = 120, OrderShippingAmount = 13, OrderStatus = "Not Shipped", CustomerEmail = "lostaunaum@gmail.com", CustomerName = "Tricia Mc.", CustomerAddress1 = "803 Jessie St.", CustomerAddress2 = "", CustomerState = "TX", CustomerZip = 78704, CustomerCity = "Austin", CustomerCountry = "United States"},

            new Order { OrderId = 3, OrderNumber = 0003, OrderDate = "03/09/2015", OrderTotal = 120, OrderShippingAmount = 14, OrderStatus = "Not Shipped", CustomerEmail = "lostaunaum@gmail.com", CustomerName = "Yusef", CustomerAddress1 = "803 Jessie St.", CustomerAddress2 = "", CustomerState = "TX", CustomerZip = 78704, CustomerCity = "Austin", CustomerCountry = "United States"},

            new Order { OrderId = 4, OrderNumber = 0003, OrderDate = "03/09/2015", OrderTotal = 120, OrderShippingAmount = 14, OrderStatus = "Not Shipped", CustomerEmail = "lostaunaum@gmail.com", CustomerName = "Paul", CustomerAddress1 = "803 Jessie St.", CustomerAddress2 = "", CustomerState = "TX", CustomerZip = 78704, CustomerCity = "Austin", CustomerCountry = "United States"},
            };
            //context.Orders.Add(orders[0]);
            orders.ForEach(o => context.Orders.Add(o));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my OrderInitialize.cs page taking into consideration that all my files are correct and that my database is properly connected to my visual studio project. Why is my database not getting the data seeded into it? This is the result i get after running Update-Database in my PM console.

```
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
```

I am trying to seed the database first then create methods to allow a user to manually input an order delete an order update an order etc.....

Any Help would be awesome.

Comment: I'm not a c# guru, but I think you have to migrate first

Comment: Hey man thanks for the answer! To all the people reading this I figured it out! When you are trying to migrate do not put your migration stuff on your WhateverNameInitialize.cs file even though it seems like it should go there. You need to put this code in your Configuration.cs then you will see your migrations actually populating your SQL files! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man thanks for the answer! To all the people reading this I figured it out! When you are trying to migrate do not put your migration stuff on your WhateverNameInitialize.cs file even though it seems like it should go there. You need to put this code in your Configuration.cs then you will see your migrations actually populating your SQL files! :D –